# What is the difference between a Mannequin and a Womennequin?

Tags: terraria

I wanted to show of some of my coolest gear in Terraria. When I was crafting a Mannequin, I saw a Womannequin crafting recipe. I have no idea what is the difference between both the statues.

And so, is there even any difference?

Comment: The **Man**nequin is a man and the **Woman**nequin is a woman?  Fairly self-evident in their names, no?

Comment: The womannequin has bewbequins.

Answer (score 20):

According [Terraria Wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Womannequin), the difference is that it will show your gear in their female sprites. So if your character is female and you want to show **exactly** how does your gear look, you need the Womannequin.

Answer (score 4):

Gear appears slightly differently when equipped by male or female characters. The mannequin displays armor exactly as if a male character were wearing it, while a womannequin displays armor exactly as if a female character were wearing it.